# Setting up Magento on a new directory

Tags: php, magento, error-handling

I am having troubles setting up my Magento shop on a new directory. I am getting the following errors:

`PDOException Object
(
    [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'core_resource' already exists
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 42S01
    [file:protected] => /home/vipcomau/public_html/archive/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
    [line:protected] => 276
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/vipcomau/public_html/archive/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
                    [line] => 276
                    [function] => query
                    [class] => PDO
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => CREATE TABLE`core_resource`(`
code`varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',`
version`varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Resource version registry'
                        )`
 http://www.timepilot.com.au/archive/

To setup the site I followed this guide: http://www.itworld.com/article/2833094/it-management/how-to-copy-a-magento-installation-to-a-new-domain.html

So after downloading the files, re uploading them to a new directory, changing the urls within the SQL file and deleting the cache folders as instructed I am having no luck.

I have changed index_cache.php to help with another error I was getting, here is the code I changed:

```
<?php
define('__AITDIR__', '/home/vipcomau/public_html/archive'); 
define('__ADMINPATH__', 'admin');
define('__AITDEBUG__', 0);

if(__AITDIR__ == '-' . '/home/vipcomau/public_htm/archive') {
//__AITDIR__ = dirname(__FILE__);
define('__AITDIR__', dirname(__FILE__)); 
}
if(__ADMINPATH__ == '-' . 'admin') {
//__ADMINPATH__ = 'admin';
define('__ADMINPATH__', 'admin'); 
}

require_once(__AITDIR__ . '/lib/Aitpagecache/config.php');


// minifier m.php
if(isset($_GET['minifier'])) {
    aitMinifier();
    exit();
}
```

I have no PHP coding skills and I am struggling to read the errors.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you at least post the complete error you're getting? And try to isolat the code you post to the one that's giving you an error.

Comment: It appears Magento is attempting to re-run its installation scripts. Can you further describe how you are moving the magento installation over?

Comment: @VladimirRamik thanks for your comment. So I took the site from the main directory (using the FTP), created a new directory called "Archive", placed the files back into that folder, exported the SQL file updated the urls and then re-uploaded it.

Comment: Please double check that your main site app/etc/local.xml matches main site database settings and archive site archive/app/etc/local.xml matches archive database settings. Its likely pointing to the main database.

Comment: @VladimirRamik I have made a new db and uploaded the SQL file and updated the local.xml, know I get these errors: 'Warning: require_once(/home/vipcomau/public_html/archive/lib/aitpagecache/Session/Factory.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vipcomau/public_html/archive/lib/Aitpagecache/config.php on line 72

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/vipcomau/public_html/archive/lib/aitpagecache/Session/Factory.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/vipcomau/public_html/archive/lib/Aitpagecache/config.php on line 72'

Comment: Looks like the module settings of aitpagecache need to be updated as well. Search core_config_data table for aitpagecache entries to see if you can direct them to the subfolder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72632/discussion-between-sam-marchant-and-vladimir-ramik).